# Should the number of individuals or the number of attempts be the denominator in this question?

Tags: probability

Let's just say we have 161 participants trying to make a free-throw shot in basketball. Of these 161:

- 71 make it on their first shot
- 23 make it on their second shot (2
  shots total)
- 2 make it on their third shot (3 shots total)
- 65 take a
  combined total of 94 shots before giving up

So a total of 219 shots were taken. If posed the question **"What is the chance of making a free-throw shot on your first try"**, using this dataset, is the answer 71/219 (32.4%), or is the answer 71/161 (44.0%)?

Comment: The denominator should be the number of first shots (presumably the number of individuals, unless some gave up before they started)

Comment: Do you even know how many shots there were in total?

Comment: @Henry 219 shots taken were taken.

Comment: So what you're saying then is 71/161, since 161 first shots were taken.

Comment: @Henry I edited my post, I had cumulative numbers in there instead of actuals.